# How to pass token while calling EWS endpoint using proxy generated classes (ExchangeServicePortTypeClient) not through EWSManagedAPI

Tags: oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices, soap-client

I am having a console application which uses Exchange Web Services OnPrem using proxy generated classes like below

var client = new ExchangeServicePortTypeClient("EndPointConfigName", ".XXXXX.asmx");

It works fine. Now I want to do the same for Exchange Online but with that it's OAuth authentication and requires token to pass.

I am generating token using registered application id, tenant id and certificate however, not sure how exactly I can add it with "ExchangeServicePortTypeClient" object.

I see ExchangeServicePortTypeClient has some token specific properties but not getting how exactly I can do.

Due to that I am getting exception "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm=""'".

I believe i would need some changes in my binding(tried both basichhttpbinding and wshttpbinding) as well but not getting what would work for OAuth authentication.

Just sample. I tried with all the possible options like Windows, Basic, None, Certificate...

```
 <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="*" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
 </security>
```

Can you please suggest how I can achieve this ?
Please note I am able to do this using EWSManagedAPI as well as Service call using "HttpWebRequest" [passing token like getFolderRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);]

However, my requirement is to do using proxy generated classes.

Comment: What I do is override GetWebResponse in ExchangeServiceBinding https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2020/06/modifying-your-ews-wsdl-proxy-code-for.html

Comment: Thanks @GlenScales this sounds like a good solution but in my case there is one challenge. In my project I am not getting "ExchangeServiceBinding" reference as WSDL proxy classes generated using service reference and not like web reference approach (.net 2.0). Hence I have "ExchangeServicePortTypeClient" so no option to override GetWebResponse. Pz can you suggest some solution in this situation ? You can get some info about ExchangeServicePortTypeClient here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623169/exchangeservicebinding-ews-exchange-web-service  Thanks!

Comment: @GlenScales I did try generating as webreference from the Advance option as suggested in the stackoverflow link I have shared but I would have 2 similar references in project and everywhere It would create ambiguity in references and have to update all the references and too much code change. Appreciate if you can suggest something here. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi @GlenScales anything you could suggest with "ExchangeServicePortTypeClient" as I can't use "ExchangeServiceBinding" ? Thanks!

Comment: The method your trying to use I don't believe is supported (I've never seen it documented or anybody using it other then mistaking selecting the wrong reference type in Visual Studio). It must generate some sort of underlying proxy code so I would think that is where you need to possible make changes or override.

Comment: I am really surprised why there is no any official microsoft documentation of "ExchangeServicePortTypeClient" as that seems to be very much supported after adding service reference of web service. For me it's working since a decade now only challenge came now as a need to add bearer token as header. I will keep digging about any possible option to intercept request and add header to it. Thanks for your help! @GlenScales